# Unit Testing F# Code Throws Null Reference Exception, why?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I'm using the NUnit testing technique suggested in the yet to be released book "F# Deep Dives Version 12" (Sec. 2.2 "Adding Tests")

The code below executes fine compiled or interactive with **MEMOIZE** defined/undefined.  However, executing the unit test from the GUI NUnit works fine with **MEMOIZE** undefined, but it fails with a "Null Reference Exception" when **MEMOIZE** is defined. Notice memorize() uses a *Closure*.  I'm suspecting the exception is happening because some initialization code generated by the compiler is not getting executed when NUnit starts up.  What do you think?

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic

open NUnit.Framework 
open FsUnit

let memoize (f: 'T -> 'U) =
    let t = new Dictionary<'T, 'U>(HashIdentity.Structural)
    fun n ->
        if t.ContainsKey n then t.[n]
        else let res = f n
             t.Add(n, res)
             res

//TODO: Insure J>0 & K>0 & J<K
let isMult = 
#if MEMOIZE
    memoize (fun (j,k) -> k % j = 0)
#else
    (fun (j,k) -> k % j = 0)
#endif

type ``Given the isMult function``() = 
    [<TestCase(3,1,false)>]
    [<TestCase(3,2,false)>]
    [<TestCase(3,3,true)>] 
    [<TestCase(5,10,true)>]
    [<TestCase(3,15,true)>]
    [<TestCase(5,13,false)>]
    [<TestCase(5,15,true)>]
    member t.``the result is calculated correctly``(j, k, expected) =         
        let actual = isMult (j,k)        
        actual |> should equal expected
```

**UPDATE:**

The standalone NUnit application is version 2.6.3.13283.

"FinnNk" gave me an idea!  I installed Nuget package "NUnitTestAdapter".  Now I can test directly within VS 2013.  No surprises, though.  I get all tests 'green' when MEMORIZE is undefined and all tests 'red' when it is defined.

The exception is still the same: "Null Reference Exception".  However, now that it executes in the IDE, I can have the debugger stop on the exception.  All I can determine so far at the breakpoint is that it needs the symbols from:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.pdb
```

I installed the new VS 2015 Preview Edition.  Nothing different happens in that environment.  Now that .NET Framework is open source, maybe I can zero the debugger precisely on the problem with the source code for "mscorlib".

Comment: My guess is you are compiling as  `.exe` rather than a `.dll` or that the test runner violates some F# assumptions.

Comment: Which runner are you using? For me in VS2013 using the built in runner or using the NUnit GUI runner your code works as expected when I define MEMOIZE (I added some printing to be sure). The Resharper runner also works, but the tests show up twice with half of them skipped for some reason.

Comment: See my addendum to my original post

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your NUnit tests in multiple threads? Normal dictionary is not thread-safe so weird things can happen. How about if you use ConcurrentDictionary, will it give the same result?

```
let memoize (f: 'T -> 'U) =
    let t = System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<'T, 'U>()
    fun n -> t.GetOrAdd(n, f)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13526564)

Comment: I would have, but comments can't have multi line code, can they?